# Compare YEAR value in WHERE clause

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

Using SQL Server 2008 R2 I am trying to compare year values in a where clause like so:

```
AND year(convert(date, (LEFT(formAuditLog, 10)), 104 )) = year(GETDATE())
```

But I get this error:

> Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string

I have also tried this but get that same result:

```
AND cast(year(convert(date, (LEFT(formAuditLog, 10)), 104 )) as int) = cast(year(GETDATE()) AS INT)
```

Note - `formAuditLog` is a string. I am getting the first 10 chars which is always `mm/dd/yyyy` (I have triple checked this) so I convert as a date and then get the year of this. Based on this info, should I not be able to do this comparison?

Thanks in advance

Added :
Note - When I put this in a select it works. I get the year part of the date I am expecting:

```
select top 10 year(convert(date, (LEFT(formAuditLog, 10)), 104 )) , * from myTableName
```

So why would this be allowed in a select but fail in a where clause?

Added : For completeness, there is actually nothing wrong with either of the two SQL bits at the top of this post.  As mentioned in the accepted post comment below, it was a leading quote in one formAuditLog records that cause it to fall over

Comment: If you drop the `top 10` from your test query does it still work? (Don't you just hate that one bad row?) Is there some reason you don't just pull the four characters representing the year and convert to an `INT` without going through a `DATE`? (`declare @AuditLog as VarChar(100) = '07/04/1776 mumble';
select @AuditLog as AuditLog, Cast( Substring( @AuditLog, 7, 4 ) as Int ) as AuditYear;`)

Comment: can you show sample data in formAuditLog column?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your `formAuditLog` column is a string like you suggest and the left 10 characters is equivalent to a date format `MM/DD/YYYY`. This should have worked for you:

```
create table mytableName (id int, formAuditLog varchar(50));

insert into mytableName values
(1,'01/02/20141203'),
(2,'01/03/20151203'),
(3,'05/01/20151203');


select 
      id,
      formAuditLog,
      cast(left(formAuditLog,10) as date) as DateField,
      year(cast(left(formAuditLog,10) as date)) as yearfield
from mytableName
where year(cast(left(formAuditLog,10) as date)) = year(cast(getdate() as date));
```

[<kbd>**Code Demo**</kbd>](http://rextester.com/NIC89213)

Comment: It was a data issue with one formAuditLog value.   I found one record with leading quotes.  So not only does your where suggestion work so does my original.   Thank you for your time and adive

Comment: Might I suggest you choose an appropriate data type to store a date... like `DATE` for instance.

Comment: Hi Nick.  yes its awful, this is part of the issue I have inherited.   Plan b of this exercise is to use this random date in this text field and insert this into a date type filed.  Then let getDate() take over from there.

Answer (score 0):

for sql server 2008, this should be your `where` condition

```
    and year(GETDATE()) = case when isdate(LEFT(formAuditLog, 10))=1 then year(convert(date, (LEFT(formAuditLog, 10)))) else  99999 end
```

For sql server 2012..

```
 AND  year(  try_parse(LEFT(formAuditLog, 10) as date)  ) = year(GETDATE())
```

Comment: Hi there.  I get  'try_parse' is not a recognized built-in function name.  I am using 2008r2, should it be available to me?   Looks like this is 2014+

Comment: you can use ISDATE in sqlserver2008

Comment: try_parse is available in versions 2012+.